# Encrypt Sting in JSP... Decrypt in PHP

Tags: php, jsp, encryption

I have to make a handshake page in php that will take a querystring that is encrypted for a function in Java/JSP and decrypt it in PHP fir use in an application.

I have found this to be a good starting point http://propaso.com/blog/?cat=6 but it encrypts in PHP and decrypts in PHP, the reverse of what I need to do.

Anyone know common Ciphers in PHP/JSP to use.  From the link above it seems the CBC is an answer, Code Below:

PHP Cipher/Mode:

```
$cipher     = "rijndael-128";
$mode       = "cbc";
```

and JSP Cipher:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
```

Anyone know of a good link to help me get this process reversed and encrypt in JSP and decrypt in PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an IV that is not predictable for a given message. Hard-coding the IV makes it predictable. So you need to devise some way to pass the IV with the ciphertext. The IV doesn't have to be kept secret though, unlike the key.

A block cipher operates on a block of plaintext of a fixed size. If you don't have enough plaintext to input, it has to be padded in such a way that a recipient can distinguish the padding from the data. The linked example completely ignores this, and that is an error. If a `CipherOutputStream` is used, a partial final block will be truncated silently from the ciphertext. If the `Cipher` object is used directly, an partial block will cause the `doFinal` method to raise an exception. Instead, use something like PKCS5Padding.

A proper Java example would be something like this:

```
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
AlgorithmParameters param = cipher.getParameters();
/* In addition to ciphertext in "cos", recipient needs IV. */
byte[] iv = param.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(output, cipher);
byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
while (true) {
  int n = input.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
  if (n < 0)
    break;
  cos.write(buf, 0, n);
}
cos.flush();
```

Where is the JSP receiving plaintext to be encrypted? How do you want the JSP to format its output (including the IV)?

Answer (score 0):

http://schneimi.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/aes-128bit-encryption-between-java-and-php/

found the answer thanks

Comment: The linked article has many of the same mistakes included in the first link you posted.